# jquery script only works in IE 7 but I need cross compatibility

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, jquery-animate

Any reason as to why this script won't work in any other browser. HERE'S the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3Msd/3/)

The effect in IE 7, which is correct...is that the menu scrolls down and as you hover over the menu items and they animate by shifting to the right for the "on hover" of an `<li> object`.

The effect in FF 3.5 is **incorrect**. The menu dropdowns, will scroll down when you hover OUT and stay scrolled down until hover IN. The animation flickers and doesn't shift the hovered in cell.

I'm using this in the header

```
      <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this is my script code

```
  <div id="menu_container"> 

           <ul id="menu"> 
            <li><a href="#">Home </a></li>
             <li><a href="#" id="places">About Us</a> 
                <ul id="dropdown1"> 
                    <li><a href="http://google.com">Our Founder</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li><a href="#">Meet The Team</a> 
                <ul id="dropdown2"> 
                    <li><a href="#">Our Founder</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Our Directors</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Our Teachers</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Employment Opportunities</a></li> 

                </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Adults</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

              <li><a href="#">Programs</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Student Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Adult Programs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Business Program</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
               <li><a href="#">Press Releases</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sponsoring Partnerships</a></li>
        </ul> 

    </div> 
   </div> 
    <div id="mid_header"> 


    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript" > 


    $(function() {
        $('#menu li li').hover(function() {

            $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: '+=15px' }, 300);

        }, function() {

            $(this).animate({ paddingLeft: '-=15px' }, 300);

        });

        $("#menu li").hover(function() {

            $(this).find("ul").slideToggle(400);

            $(this).find("a").toggleClass("dropdownhoverIn");


        });


    });

</script>
```

Comment: Please include a jsFiddle or something.... [ **like this** ](http://jsfiddle.net/t3Msd/)

Comment: I added the fiddle but it doesn't even do the jquery part...I included the link in my post.

Comment: Ok the JSFiddle is now working and my problem persists. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks hilarious when you run it! What fun, everything shifting around like that.

Ok, this is from the slideToggle documentation: If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is saved and restored as needed.

So I did this and it behaves better in Firefox 3 and IE8:

```
$("#menu li ul").hide(); // <--- I added this line
$("#menu li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideToggle(400);
    $(this).find("a").toggleClass("dropdownhoverIn");
});
```

Comment: Ah you beat me to it. Hey that works great! Did you change the Jquery or css? Please help me learn!

Comment: Hey Ehsan, actually with jsfiddle I was able to fix your code and send you to the new version. Pretty slick. See my description above for the details of how I fixed it (using jquery) and why it works. I only had to add that one line of code.

Comment: I see you added the $("menu li ul").hide() I totally missed that one! wow I feel dumb. Thanks mate.